# How to manipulate time objects in Python?

Tags: python, datetime, time

I need to work with `datetime` but I can't find how to subtract or add minutes or seconds from a `datetime.time` object

I've tried to use datetime.timedelta but it doesn't work.

Here is what I've tried

```
t1=datetime.time(15,45,20)
t2=t1-datetime.timedelta(seconds=40)
```

I would like to obtain `t2=datetime.time(15,44,40)`

Comment: Please clarify *"doesn't work"* with a [mcve]. There's a reason it requires a full `datetime` - what should happen if subtracting 40 seconds takes you into the previous day?

Comment: You can't subtract a timedelta from a time, only from a datetime.  Also, your question title is misleading, as you apparently don't want to manipulate dates at all, only times.

Answer (score 1):

Timedelta works with datetime objects.
You could make your time into a datetime (or just start with one, who cares what the year, etc is), and then extract a time object back out.

```
>>>t1=datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 1, 15,45,20)
>>>t2=t1-datetime.timedelta(seconds=40)
>>>print t2.time()
15:44:40
>>>type(t2.time())
<type 'datetime.time'>
```

As one of the comments pointed out, this can give you odd results if you don't think about it. Take 40 seconds off, and end up with a time that's later (but a day earlier on the date data you are ignoring). But you can work around that with minimal logic to catch things that are going to go over 24:00:00 or under 0:0:0.